# Implements a sliding menu without sliding drawer Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gesture

I'm trying to implement a sliding menu without using the sliding drawer element deprecated. I see a lot of examples but all of them use sliding drawer or haven't complete code. Can you post some example or library to solve my problem?

Comment: Another info: i must have the layout always visible and a layout similar as handler in Sliding drawer

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Easy to implement, just add java code of example and create your menu.xml

Comment: why ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: I try the demo....the menu is from left/right to right/left.....I must implement a menu from bottom to top

Answer (score 1):

You can check out  [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)